# Is "Listen Nations" referring to any incident in particular?

Tags: song-lyrics, yerachmiel-begun

"Listen Nations" is one of the songs on the album [Miami Meets Toronto](https://mostlymusic.com/products/miami-meets-toronto-cd), in which the Miami Boys Choir and the Toronto Boys Choir (both started by Yerachmiel Begun) sing together. The song is about the suffering of people, and the nations of the world not caring. The chorus is:

> And when I saw it
>   The thought I could not bear
>   My fellow people dying
>   Their cries no one did hear
>   So listen nations
>   To the voices of those so dear

I added the lyrics to [musixmatch.com](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Yerachmiel-Begun-The-Miami-Boys-Choir/Listen-Nations), so you can view the lyrics.

But is this song referring to anything in particular? I.e., the Holocaust (it's Jewish music, BTW). If so, is there anything in the text that shows this?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a copy (both audio and lyrics) online, and my copy of the album is at home. My feeling is that it's *probably* related to the Holocaust, but I'm not sure. It might also be a good idea to look at what year it was written, and also for Begun interviews. (The newish Endnotes section of *Mishpacha* comes to mind, but I don't know if this particular song was ever covered there.)

Comment: [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_Boys_Choir#Discography), *Miami Meets Toronto* is from 1978.